# Dynamic queries in Stubby4node

Tags: node.js, stub

I'm trying to do something like that:

```
# Destination by ID
- request:
....
    query:
      serviceId: "s009"

  response:
    file: destinations/destination-by-service-id-$serviceId.json
...
```

So the serviceId would match the file destination-by-service-id-$serviceId.json instead of having to create several files to match different service id's, like s008, s010, etc...

Is that something we can do with stubby?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same in [stubby-db](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/StubbyDB).

```
# Destination by ID
- request:
....
    url: someurl?serviceId=([0-9a-z]+)

  response:
    file: destinations/destination-by-service-id-<% url.1 %>.json
...
```